# Keep element that is being dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I am making a drag event, but when I do it, I want to keep the element i was trying to drag.

Here is what I tried to do.

```
function drag(ev) {

ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
console.log(document.getElementById(data));
document.getElementById("tareas").append(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

In the `console.log` of `document.getElementById(data)` I get this

```
<p id="item1" class="text-danger materias" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Cambio aceite</p>
```

but it doesnt stay, if anybody can give me an idea on how to keep the element.
thanks. 
(Edit) adding images

[image: initial state]

I want the item to stay on the same place it was at first.
[image]

Comment: It doesn't stay where you dragged it to you mean?

Comment: Edited with images, I want the item to stay on the first position, but also to be dragged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the move the element to the new location, you can clone it first, then append the new element there.

e.g.: Change your last line in `drag()` to be:

```
document.getElementById("tareas").append(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
```

Comment: This does keep the element, but now for example I move one element to the table, it clones it but when I move the same element again to the table, it gets cloned again but doesnt move

Comment: What do you mean by move the same element again? If you want to prevent same item being added to the target place twice, then you need to add some validation before you call the `.addend()`. Perhaps you can provide more code or create a JSFiddle to better describe your issue.